# Robust image URL linking from CSS?

Tags: html, css, grails, groovy, resources

Is there a good way to robustly link to an image in CSS in grails? Originally, I had image paths set to `/images/blah`, which worked great until the application needed to be deployed in a different context.

Is there a better way to link to images than manually specifying the path to the images relative to the css file? This leaves me with crap like `../../../images/blah`, which breaks as soon as the CSS file moves unless you move the file within a smart IDE. This is also ugly as hell.

Comment: I don't know Grails, but does it happen that often that the CSS file moves and the relative paths break? Relative URLs are pretty much the ideal method IMO unless you want to start injecting dynamic paths into your style sheets (which can be expensive and add complexity)

Comment: There is no way to specify a url if you want to both move the css, and the images around independently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using Grails tag libraries with the GSParse plugin to have css and js parsed as a gsp file:

http://nerderg.com/GSParse

http://grails.org/plugin/gsp-arse

Comment: This looks like it needs to be migrated to integrate with the resources plugin.